# Ipv6 DS-Lite issue with portforwarding

Tags: networking

Want to open some ports or at least a VPN port on my rpi4.
My cable router supports only ipv6 and they call it DS-Lite.
Port forwarding is done by eth0's Mac address and for test reasons, I opened the range of 80 - 8888.

I created a dyn DNS at no-ip (as I am using for other PCs) with AAAA record and its ipv6 address.

unfortunately, only port 80 works as my apache2 sends a test web page. All other ports are not being delivered regardless of what port I am using.

Want to open port 1194 for open VPN or 8083 for them. But this is not delivered outside.

Any idea folks?

Thanks

PS: I am running some apps like OpenVPN or them or Webmin and their ports are working on the intranet but not outside. No UFW is active.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check with your ISP.  They may not permit OpenVPN packets or ports and might be blocking at the border of their network before it even gets to your system.  This is not uncommon with ISPs and residential networks.

Comment: The thing is, no other ports are working. Only 80

Answer (score 0):

First check if the internet router from your ISP uses a firewall. If yes, you need to open the ports you want to use, and forward them to your raspi.

You can check the open ports of your ISP router from outside using the following command.

```
nmap -p 1-65535 -T4 -A -v [IP-address-of-your-router]
```

May be, you can configure a DMZ in your ISP router. If so, add your raspi to the DMZ.